# Real life deck shuffle java

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array

```
public static void embaralhar(Carta bar[]){
        
        for(int i=0;i<=1;i++)
        {
            
            int monteMenor=(int) (Math.random()*(bar.length/2-1))+1;
            int posição=(int) (Math.random()*(bar.length-monteMenor))+1;
            Carta aux[] = new Carta[monteMenor];
                for (int j=0; j<monteMenor; j++) { 
                    aux[j]=bar[bar.length-monteMenor+j];
                    bar[bar.length-monteMenor+j]=null;
                }
            
            for(int j=0;j<monteMenor;j++)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println();
                for (int k =bar.length-monteMenor; k>posição+j; k--) { 
                    bar[k+1] = bar[k];   
                    
                    System.out.println();
                }
                bar[posição+j]=aux[j];  
                
            }
            
            
        }   
        
        
    }
```

Im trying to make a code to simulate a real life shufle of a deck by taking a random amount of cards `monteMenor` and then put them back in another random position `posição`
I have to use an array of cards `bar` with objects `carta` but this code is always giving me more than 2 equal cards
Anyone can help me fix this?

Comment: There is a [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List)) method you can use

Comment: No it has to be simulating a real life way to shufle cards not a random like java can do in case it wasnt clear enough its about a homework i have to do for a class i cant "cheat"

Comment: Exactly what do you mean with `real life shuffle`? There are several different ways to shuffle cards.

Comment: I mean a code that is similar to what you would do in real life to shuffle a deck this one is take a random number of cards and put them back at a random position in the deck like real people do not like a normal java function that put cards in random places